# Is there any .Net JIT Support from chip vendors?

Tags: .net, runtime, cpu, jit, vm-implementation

I know that ARM actually has some support for Java and SUN obviously, but I haven't really references seen any chip vendor supporting a .Net JIT compiler.  I know IBM and Intel both support C compilers, as well as TI and many of the embedded chip vendors.  When you think of it, all a JIT compiler is, is the last stages of compilation and optimization which you would think would be a good match for a chip vendor's expertize.  Perhaps a standardized Plug In compilation engine for the VM would make sense.

Microsoft is targeting .Net to embedded Windows platforms as well, so they are fair game.

Pete

Answer (score 2):

The [Meridian CPU](http://www.devicesolutions.net/?_kk=c%23%20embedded&_kt=284cd1e9-1d24-4400-ba60-22e716e7f99c&gclid=CMGukqStqZwCFSYoawodR1iUjw) supports the .NET micro framework directly.

Comment: Supports yes.  However this is an implementation of .net micro framework (which was designed for microcontrollers) implemented in an existing CPU.  I think the asker was after optimisation in desktop type processors for .Net or JIT.

Comment: Well, it's still a specific chip vendor supporting a JIT that's oriented for .NET.  I agree that a vendor specific JIT may have value for desktop processors, as well, but this still seemed like it fit into the question, and it's the only one I know of off the top of my head.

Comment: No, embedded are platforms are valid. I would expect a big push for it to be supprort on x86 due to the fact it's Microsoft though.  Embedded Windows platforms are targets for .Net as well.

Comment: Point I was making is supporting a platform and specifically optimising for it are two different things.  There is no special hardware in this chip to support .Net it's simply a platform that was targetted by .Net micro framework.

Answer (score 1):

A better question here is "Are there any processors out there that directly implement the .Net IL as their machine instructions". IL is a form of assembler code, and one wonder why we don't see hardware that support this instruction set directly, if it did then we would not need any JIT compilation.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specifically or clearly said which platform is of interest. dotnet is very much tied to the windows platform which itself requires x86. That said unless intel add some emulation layer into the die the answer is no. .dotnet without windows is worthless.

Answer (score -1):

JIT compilation happens once at startup.  Why optimise this?  Optimising the garbage collector through caches, possibly assisting the program with dedicated CPU registers and instructions for performing sweeps and allocation would increase program speed.

It's interesting though because after your .Net code is JIT compiled it's using techniques which are already optimised for performing these things, such as double dereference pointer instructions, and I'm certain that the CLR would have been implemented to keep commonly used parts of the framework in registers for speed etc.

But lets hope that whole "competition" thing thats meant to happen between AMD and Intel brings this on.  If you're buying a server for a java or .Net implementation and your server with chip X will run 10% faster at the same cost because garbage collected langagues are optimised for it, which would you buy?

Comment: The JIT is what compiles it to the native architecture. I'm not talking about optimizing the process, but the x86 or PowerPC (Xbox) code that is generated.  I imagine that Microsoft intends for it to be used on all it's Windows embedded products regardless of the processor type as well.

Comment: What do you mean?  The JIT code is optimised by the .Net compiler already.  It's just x86 code that gets spat out the end of a compiler which is optimised to it's platform.  You can't realistically do this in hardware as compilation is too high a level operation.  However optimising the CLR so that code written to target garbage collected languages may well be optimised by targetted registers, caches and instructions.